# How should I approach the understanding of "array.forEach(function) " in the code attached?

Tags: javascript

```
function Counter()
    { this.sum = 0;
    this.count = 0;
     }

Counter.prototype.add = function(array){
array.forEach(function(entry){
this.sum+= entry;
++this.count;
},this);
};

var obj = new Counter();
obj.add([2,5,9]);
console.log(obj.count);
// 3
console.log(obj.sum);
//16
```

What does the ++ sign does here?
I know this is a contrived example,and it is an array.forEach(function())
application. But I don't seem to understand this.arg very well. Please walk me through this code. And why it is the outputs are 3 and 16

Comment: *Please walk me through this code. And why it is the outputs are 3 and 16* - Best one to help you here is javascript debugger in Chrome/ Firefox. Open up developer tools/ F12 and give it a try.

Comment: ++this.count here is equivalent to this.count = this.count + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this[arg]` refers to a property of the "class" `Counter`. `this.count` is some counter that's saying how many times `this.sum` has been increased. `++` just increments something by 1.

In other words, if some variable `foo` is `0`, `foo++` is the same as `foo = foo + 1`.

Basically it goes like this...

You passed in `[2, 5, 9]`, and `forEach` loops over each value.

First iteration:

`this.sum = this.sum + 2 // => 2`

`this.count = this.count + 1 // => 1`

Second iteration:

`this.sum = this.sum + 5 // => 2 + 5 = 7`

`this.count = this.count + 1 // => 1 + 1 = 2`

Last iteration:

`this.sum = this.sum + 7 // => 7 + 9 = 16`

`this.count = this.count + 1 // => 2 + 1 = 3`

And thus, you get 16 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `Counter` object :

```
var obj = new Counter();
```

You call the `add()` function of the `Counter` Object with as parameter an array with the number `2`, `5` and `9`:

```
obj.add([2,5,9]);
```

About the `add()` function :

```
Counter.prototype.add = function(array){
  function(array){
    array.forEach(function(entry){
      this.sum+= entry;
      ++this.count;
     },this);
  };
```

For each element of the array, the `forEach()` function makes two things :

- increment the `sum` number variable by summing each element of the array :

  `this.sum+= entry;`
- increment the `count` number variable as soon as a `forEach()` invocation is done:

  `++this.count;`

`++this.count;` is a pre increment operator. It means that count is increment during this statement.

In this context, it changes nothing as you don't use the result of the incrementation in the same statement.
You could use `this.count++;`.

If for example, you would increment and output this new value in the console in the same statement, it would make sense :

```
var count = 0;
console.log(++this.count); // display 1
```

With pre increment, the new value would be reflected only in the next statement:

```
var count = 0;
console.log(this.count++); // display 0
console.log(this.count); // display 1
```